# Como bloquear parte de um método para ser processado apenas uma vez por requisição com .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, concorrência

eu tenho que incrementar uma coluna no banco de dados e este incremento pode depender da situação, por exemplo incrementar de acordo com o usuário, eu estou utilizando Jmeter para enviar 100 requisições ao mesmo tempo, porem todas elas estão sendo executadas de uma vez, na hora de salvar eu precisava fazer uma logica para incrementar o valor da coluna eu tentei utilizar o lock e o SemaphoreSlim, mas quando envio as requisições o servidor fica parado e não executa nada quando chega no lock ou no _semaphore.Wait() as requisições não passam, estou utilizando NHibernate, como posso fazer esse tipo de função bloquear parte de um método para ser executado uma vez de cada.

```
private static readonly object _lock = new object();

public override DepositoProduto Save(DepositoProduto entity)
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //aqui a função do auto incremento pode depende no caso coloquei um exemplo simples
            entity.Codigo = All().OrderByDescending(x = > x.Codigo).Select(x = > x.Codigo).First() + 1;

            //aqui realiza o save no banco
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Utilizando SemaphoreSlim

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public override DepositoProduto Save(DepositoProduto entity)
{
    _semaphore.Wait();
    using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //aqui a função do auto incremento pode depende no caso coloquei um exemplo simples
        entity.Codigo = All().OrderByDescending(x = > x.Codigo).Select(x = > x.Codigo).First() + 1;

        //aqui realiza o save no banco
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    _semaphore.Release();
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: Está usando *thread*?

Comment: não, o método é um ActionResult esse metodo " override DepositoProduto Save" é chamado no final do ActionResult antes do retorno

Comment: Então não tem porque sincronizar métodos, se a execução não é concorrente não tem problema algum. Se o problema vem de outro lugar é erro de arquitetura e não de código. Este código está cheio de complicações para zero benefício, provavelmente tentando arrumar um erro que veio de outra decisão errada.

Comment: Bom, praticamente é concorrente sim, porque chegar varias requisições no ActionResult  e todas são executadas ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Não existe praticamente concorrente, ou é ou não. Se não está usando *thread* então não é. O acesso aos dados pode ser concorrente e isso é problema do banco de dados lidar, você só precisa configurá-lo corretamente. Não sei se o nHibernate tem alguma ferramenta que ajude nisto. Para soluções complexas ele não é útil. Mas eu nem sei se você tem alguma solução complexa mesmo, se está tendo algum problema, mas se está parece ser problema de isolamento.